# Scope(failure) in C++11?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, destructor

I wrote a very simple solution however someone laughed and found a flaw as shown here http://ideone.com/IcWMEf

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <functional>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

// Wrong scope(failure)
class FailBlockT
{
    typedef function<void()> T;
    public:
    T t;
    FailBlockT(T t)
    {
        this->t=t;
    }
    ~FailBlockT()
    {
        if (std::uncaught_exception())
        {
            t();
        }
    }
};

struct Test
{
    ~Test()
    {
        try
        {
            FailBlockT f([]()
            {
                cout << "failure" << endl;
            });
            // there is no any exception here, but "failure" is printed.
            // See output below
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            cout << "some exception" << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Test t;
        throw 1;
    }
    catch(int){}
    return 0;
}
```

In short the problem is my code looks at `std::uncaught_exception()`. When an exception is thrown and a normal destructor is executed. If i use scope failure there it will look at `std::uncaught_exception()` and think the object scope is lost due to exception rather then simply walking out of scope.

I can't think of any good solutions to **differentiate leaving scope normally VS having an exception thrown IN it**. Yes i know throwing is a bad idea in dtors BUT thats why I fail to notice this problem, because I never throw in exceptions.

How do I differentiate/solve this?

Comment: It's not really clear what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @sth I bolded it, does that help?

Comment: @acidzombie24: OK, let's try it this way. *Why* do you want to "**differentiate leaving scope normally VS having an exception thrown IN it**"? And more specifically, why do you need to do that in a destructor, who's sole purpose should just be to clean up after the object? Why does a destructor *need* to care whether it's cleaning up due to an exception or not?

Comment: Also, what is "scope failure"?

Comment: @NicolBolas The answer to this question explains what Scope(failure) {...} is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247778/is-ds-scope-failure-success-exit-necessary and likes 37-39 in the demo shows the problem. No exception was thrown but it thinks it has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> No exception was thrown but it thinks it has.

An exception *was* thrown, just *not from right there*.

There is no mechanism in C++11 to ask, "Was an exception thrown from code just below me, but *not* from code elsewhere in the call-stack?" `std::uncaught_exception` is doing exactly what it is supposed to do: say whether there is an exception currently in the process of being resolved at the time the function is called. And there is, so it returns `true`.

C++17 adds `std::uncaught_exceptions` (note the plural), which can be used to detect the difference. With such a tool, you can make your `FailBlock` object work:

```
template<typename Func>
class FailBlockT
{
private:
    int e_count_;
    T t_;

public:
    FailBlockT(T t) : e_count_(std::uncaught_exceptions()), t_(t) {}

    FailBlock(const FailBlock &) = delete; //The type should not be mobile.

    ~FailBlockT()
    {
        if (std::uncaught_exceptions() != e_count_)
        {
            t_();
        }
    }
};
```

`std::uncaught_exceptions()` returns the number of exceptions that are provoking stack unwinding at the time the call was made. If the number is the same during the constructor and destructor of an object (assuming it's a stack object), then the destructor is not being called due to an exception being thrown through where this type was used.

But without this tool, it, there's not much you can do to differentiate between an exception provoking the exiting of the scope rather than exiting a scope when exception unwinding just happens to be going on. So you're going to have to bite the bullet and *catch* the exception like everyone else.

Or just don't put this `FailBlock` thing in destructors. It seems to me that those should go directly into regular functions that can actually throw (and destructors should never throw). It seems to me that you're worried about a corner case that doesn't make any real sense.

Comment: I see, its suppose to emulate the D feature which is suppose to get rid of catch. But I see. It would be annoying to write catch but in fail case i'll have to. I'm thinking about cheating, good thing this isnt used in production code.

Comment: @acidzombie24: `scope(failure)` doesn't get rid of `catch`. It makes it so that `catch` used for *catching* exceptions, rather than stopping exception propagation temporarily to do some cleanup. You know, it's *actual job*. It gets rid of catch-and-release nonsense. Also, I just said that `FailBlock` works exactly as you want it to as long as you don't use it in an object's destructor (or as members of objects, for that matter). So it's up to you: avoid the catch statement 99% of the time, or always write it.

Comment: My hack solution is pretty much using an assert on uncaught_exception in construction of the object. But like i said i personally don't write throwing code in dtors.

Comment: To differentiate between normal exit and exception exit, you can just have a `guard.dismiss()` right as the last line. If it is executed, your scope exited normally. If not, you got an exception (or early return).

Comment: This answer is quite old, but *[...] just don't put this `FailBlock` thing in destructors* is not enough. Destructors may do cleanup that inadvertently calls a function that uses `FailBlock` which is now broken transitively. The motivation behind it is good and with C++17 `std::uncaught_exceptions()` this is now possible to do correctly. See [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/v2020.01.27.00/folly/ScopeGuard.h) for an implementation of the concept.

Answer (score 4):

> I can't think of any good solutions to differentiate leaving scope normally VS having an exception thrown IN it.

Check [stack_unwinding library](https://github.com/panaseleus/stack_unwinding) - I have implemented scope(failure) and scope(success) features in C++.

It is based on platform specific function uncaught_exception_count. It is similar to std::uncaught_exception from standard library, but instead of boolean result it returns unsigned int showing current count of uncaught exceptions.

Currently it is tested on {Clang 3.2, GCC 3.4.6, GCC 4.1.2, GCC 4.4.6, GCC 4.4.7, MSVC2005SP1, MSVC2008SP1, MSVC2010SP1, MSVC2012} x {x32, x64}.

In C++11 folowing syntax is [available](https://github.com/panaseleus/stack_unwinding/blob/master/examples/boost_scopes_cpp11.cpp):

```
try
{
    int some_var=1;
    cout << "Case #1: stack unwinding" << endl;
    scope(exit)
    {
        cout << "exit " << some_var << endl;
        ++some_var;
    };
    scope(failure)
    {
        cout << "failure " << some_var << endl;
        ++some_var;
    };
    scope(success)
    {
        cout << "success " << some_var << endl;
        ++some_var;
    };
    throw 1;
} catch(int){}
{
    int some_var=1;
    cout << "Case #2: normal exit" << endl;
    scope(exit)
    {
        cout << "exit " << some_var << endl;
        ++some_var;
    };
    scope(failure)
    {
        cout << "failure " << some_var << endl;
        ++some_var;
    };
    scope(success)
    {
        cout << "success " << some_var << endl;
        ++some_var;
    };
}
```

In C++98 it is a bit more [noisier](https://github.com/panaseleus/stack_unwinding/blob/master/examples/boost_scopes.cpp):

```
try
{
    cout << "Case #1: stack unwinding" << endl;
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(void) { cout << "exit" << endl; } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
    SCOPE_FAILURE(void) { cout << "failure" << endl; } SCOPE_FAILURE_END
    SCOPE_SUCCESS(void) { cout << "success" << endl; } SCOPE_SUCCESS_END
    throw 1;
} catch(int){}
{
    cout << "Case #2: normal exit" << endl;
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(void) { cout << "exit" << endl; } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END
    SCOPE_FAILURE(void) { cout << "failure" << endl; } SCOPE_FAILURE_END
    SCOPE_SUCCESS(void) { cout << "success" << endl; } SCOPE_SUCCESS_END
}
```

Also, library has [UNWINDING_AWARE_DESTRUCTOR](https://github.com/panaseleus/stack_unwinding#unwinding-aware-destructor) feature. [Example](https://github.com/panaseleus/stack_unwinding/blob/master/examples/unwinding_aware_destructor.cpp):

```
struct DestructorInClass
{
    UNWINDING_AWARE_DESTRUCTOR(DestructorInClass,unwinding)
    {
        cout << "DestructorInClass, unwinding: "
             << ( unwinding ? "true" : "false" ) << endl;
    }
};
```

However, there are some cases where UNWINDING_AWARE_DESTRUCTOR may [give wrong results](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/scope-exit-D-style-scope-failure-and-scope-success-in-C-tp4636441p4636477.html) (though scope(success) and scope(failure) features are not affected by such issues).